# Where is template.sty? (Required in xfrac)

Tags: texlive, latex3, xfrac

Having just updated to TL2011, I find that the `xfrac` package fails with the error:

```
! LaTeX Error: File `template.sty' not found.
```

Sure enough, neither `kpsewhich` nor `find` can locate it.  I *can* find it in my TL2010 tree, so I could copy it over from there, I guess.  The location there is:

```
tex/latex/xpackages/xbase/template.sty
```

But there's not even a corresponding `xpackages` directory in the TL2011 tree!  My (limited) poking around in the directory structure makes it look as though the `x-stuff` has been rearranged, and several things renamed.  There *is* a suspicious looking `xtemplate.sty` file in the new TL2011 tree, but it is sufficiently different to `template.sty` that I can't be sure that they do the same thing.

So ...

1. Is `xtemplate.sty` the new `template.sty` and I should just change the line in `xfrac` to require the `x`-rated version?
2. If not, should I just copy `template.sty` over from TL2010 (in to my local `texmf` tree rather than TL2011, of course) and what else should I copy?
3. Or is there a package on CTAN that covers this (I couldn't find it via a search)?
4. Is there a new super all-singing all-dancing all-reciprocating package that replaces `xfrac` that I should use instead?

Comment: (I've tagged this [tag:latex3] because it looks like that's what got reorganised.)

Comment: If I load `xfrac.sty` (using TL 2011), it autoloads `xtemplate.sty` -- but this shouldn't require your hand to set up. Try updating your packages `tlmgr update -self -all`. If that doesn't work, add `\listfiles` to your code and post the file list, maybe.

Comment: `xtemplate` and `xfrac` itself are now [l3packages](http://ctan.org/pkg/l3packages). For me (TL 2011), `xfrac` is failing with a completely different error, which makes things even more interesting.

Comment: Yes, it seems that the LaTeX3 packages got recently reorganized, at least in TeX Live. Some packages are now installed under different named in TeX Live. This lead to automatic deinstallation of some packages and the installations of some new ones.

Comment: Aaagh!  @frabjous is completely correct.  I had downloaded `xfrac` once long ago and stashed it somewhere in my TEXMF tree (before it made it in to TL, presumably).  That was being loaded, not the TL version.  My apologies, one and all.  (Close as "too-localised"?)